# When and by whom was the term 'momentum' introduced?

Tags: physics, terminology

We know that up to 1726, when the third edition of the *Principia* was published, the name for $m\vec v$ was: *quantitas motus*.

Do you know who substituted that with another Latin word: 'momentum'?

Comment: *Momentum* was "already there" for a long time: see [Momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) : **History of the concept**. It needs a "progressive shift of meaning" to previous usage as a sort of "inner force" to the modern use.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for your response, I did not refer to the concept, but to the actual **term**, name, word that substitutes _'quantitas motus'_ = m*v. As to the wiki article you link, that is one of the worst example of misinformation by wikipedia, since Buridan's (and Galileo's) concept of impetus has nothing to do with momentum but refers to kinetic energy

Comment: The latin *momentum* (Italian : *momento*) is an "ubiquitous" term in Galileo, like *impeto* and sometimes *forza*; see Paolo Galluzzi, [Momento : studi galileiani](https://books.google.it/books?id=MIhJPQAACAAJ) (1979). It is proportional to the velocity acquired by a body in a given time. See *Discorso intorno alle cose che stanno in su l'acqua* (1612) : "io piglio dalla scienza meccanica due principii. Il primo è, che pesi assolutamente eguali, mossi con eguali velocità, sono di *forze* e di *momenti* eguali nel loro operare. 1/2

Comment: ... Momento, appresso i meccanici, significa quella virtù, quella forza, quella efficacia, con la quale il motor muove e 'l mobile resiste; la qual virtù depende non solo dalla semplice gravità, ma dalla velocità del mot [...]." Partial transl. "I borrow two principles from the Science of mechanics. The first is this - two absolutely equal weights that are moved with equal velocities are of the same power,  or the same *momento*, in all their doings. To students of mechanics, *momento* means that property [...] by which the  motive agency moves and the body resists. 2/3

Comment: ... This property does not only depend on the simple gravity, but also on the velocity of motion." 3/3

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA [Jean Buridan](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Jean_Buridan.aspx#1) (1295-1358) was the first to call it *impetus*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve found no secondary sources with specific references to this issue; here are some evidences.

Regarding Wiki reference for the term [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum), see :

- John Jennings (1721). [Miscellanea in Usum Juventutis Academicae](http://books.google.it/books?id=hMsDAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA67), **n°IX. MECHANICA**, page  67 :

> **DEFINITIO I.** *Momentum* seu *Quantitas Motus* est Rectangulum ex Quantitate Materiae in Velocitate ducta, i.e. $M=Q \times V$ .

In Isaac Newton, *Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica* (1686), we have only the mathematical term *momentum*; see :

> **Lemma II.** Momentum Genitæ æquatur momentis Terminorum singulorum generantium in eorundem laterum indices dignitatum & coefficientia continue ductis. […] Has quantitates ut indeterminatas & instabiles, & quasi motu fluxuve perpetuo crescentes vel decrescentes hic considero, & eorum incrementa vel decrementa momentanea sub nomine *momentorum* intelligo.

See [Sir Isaac Newton's Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=ySYULc7VEwsC&pg=PA249) (translated into English by Andrew Motte in 1729;  revised by Florian Cajori : 1934), **Lemma II** [page 249] :

> These quantities I here consider as variable and indetermined, and increasing or decreasing, as it were, by a continual motion or flux; and I understand their momentary increments or decrements by the name of *moments*.

I've found **no** usage of *momentum* as synonym of *quantity of motion* in most of 18th Century texts: here are some refrences :

- [William Whiston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Whiston), [Sir Isaac Newton's Mathematick Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=t3hbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA40) (1716), page 40 :

> the *Quantity of Motion* is the Measure of the same, arising from the Velocity, and from the Quantity of Matter conjunctly.

- Leonhard Euler, [Mechanica sive Motus scientia analytice exposita](https://books.google.it/books?id=8TAVAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA103) : Tomus I (1736), page 103 [art.n*263] :

> [reffering to Newton’s definition of] vis centripetae quantitatem motricem qua nihil aliud denotat nisi ipsum conatum, quem corpora habent ad centrum virium accedendi; *quantitas motus* enim, quam mensurare soliti sunt celeritate ducta in massa,s, quaeque dato tempore generatur, proportionalis est ipsi conatui.

Nor we can find the term (linear) *momentum* in the first “modern” expressions of Newton’s Law by Euler; neither in his memoir on celestial mechanics of 1747, nor in his *Decouverte d'un nouveau principe de Mecanique* (1750), page 196 [see it in [Euler archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/index.html) and see also Clifford Truesdell, [Essays in the History of Mechanic](https://books.google.it/books?id=uPLqmwEACAAJ) (1968), page 167].

- Jean-Baptiste le Rond d'Alembert, [Traité de dynamique](https://books.google.it/books?id=Kmv6sXij_uUC&pg=PA55) (nouvelle ed, 1758), page 55 [art.n*46] :

> Le produit de la masse d’un corps par sa vitesse est appellee *quantité de Mouvement*.

See also page 73 : “**DEFINITION.** […] par *quantité de Mouvement*, j’entendrai à l’ordinaire le produit de la masse par la vitesse".

- [Mathurin Jacques Brisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathurin_Jacques_Brisson) : [Traité élémentaire ou Principes de physique](https://books.google.it/books?id=NwS4s5sjq8MC&pg=PA60), (Paris 1789–1803), page 60 :

> **7. Quantité de mouvement.** La *quantité de movement* d’un corps s’estime ou s’évalue en multipliant la masse de ce corps par sa vitesse, car elle y est proportionnelle.

See also the Italian translation (3rd ed.1804) : *Trattato elementare ovvero Principj di fisica : Tomo I*, page 57 : “**VII. Quantità del moto.** La *Quantità del moto* di un corpo si valuta moltiplicando la massa di questo corpo per la velocità.”

---

We can find in Andrew Motte,  [A treatise of the mechanical powers](https://books.google.it/books?id=OnZYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA8), (1727), page 8 :

> the Product of these two, the Velocity, and the Weight of a moving Body, which is called the *Momentum* of that Body.

See also page 53:

> Two moving Bodies have equal *Momenta* or Quantities of Motion, when the Velocity of each Body multiplied into its Weight […].

See also in Colin MacLaurin, [An Account of Sir Isaac Newton's Philosophical Discoveries](https://books.google.it/books?id=yS1PAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA140) (2nd ed, 1750); see page 140 :

> the quantity of motion, or *momentum*

and page 111 :

> The *quantity of motion* in a body […] is the compounded ratio of its quantity of matter and of the velocity of the motion.

---

In 19th century, we can find it in “modern” treatises, like :

- William Thomson Baron Kelvin & Peter Guthrie Tait, *Treatise on Natural Philosophy* (2nd ed, 1879), art.210, page 221 :

> The *Quantity of Motion*, or the *Momentum*, of a rigid body moving without rotation is proportional to its mass and velocity conjointly.

and :

- James Clerk Maxwell, *Matter and Motion* (1888), art.**LI. - On Momentum** [page 44] :

> The numerical value of the *Momentum* of a body is the product of the number of units of mass in the body into the numbers of units of velocity with which it is moving.

An early reference for the English usage in 19th Century is : [Thomas Young](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Young_%28scientist%29), [A Course of Lectures on Natural Philosophy and the Mechanical Arts](https://books.google.it/books?id=lmM_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA36), (1807); I’m not able to browse volume I, but the Index point to  : I, page 52 for the definition of quantity of motion and I,53 for the definition of momentum.

In volume 2, we can find [page 36] :

> n*270 : **DEFINITION.** The joint ratio of the masses and velocities of any two bodies is the ratio of their *momenta*.
>
> n*271 : **THEOREM.** The *momentum* of any body is the true measure of the quantity of its motion.

Another possible source is Joseph-Louis Lagrange, *Mécanique analytique : Tome I* (1811), pag.27, regarding the *pricipe des vitesses virtuelles* : let $P,Q,R$ the *puissances* and let $dp,dq,dr$ proportional to the *vitesses virtuelles* of the respectives *puissances*.

Each term $P dp$ of the general equation of Statics regardings the equilibrium of the system is called :

> le moment de la force $P$, en prenant le mot de *moment* dans le sens qui Galilée lui a donné, c’set-à-dire, pour le produit de la force par sa vitesse virtuelle.

Ref to Galileo Galilei, [Le mecaniche](http://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_mecaniche/Diffinizioni) (1599) :

> […] la velocità del moto sia potente ad accrescere *momento* nel mobile, secondo quella medesima proporzione con la quale essa velocità di moto viene augumentata.
>
> Momento è la propensione di andare al basso, cagionata non tanto dalla gravità del mobile, quanto dalla disposizione che abbino tra di loro diversi corpi gravi; mediante il qual momento si vedrà molte volte un corpo men grave contrapesare un altro di maggior gravità: come nella stadera si vede un picciolo contrapeso alzare un altro peso grandissimo, non per eccesso di gravità, ma sì bene per la lontananza dal punto donde viene sostenuta la stadera; la quale, congiunta con la gravità del minor peso, gli accresce momento ed impeto di andare al basso, col quale può eccedere il momento dell'altro maggior grave. È dunque il momento quell'impeto di andare al basso, composto di gravità, posizione e di altro, dal che possa essere tal propensione cagionata.
>
> […] E da questo discorso possiamo venire in cognizione, come *la velocità del moto sia potente ad accrescere momento nel mobile, secondo quella medesima proporzione con la quale essa velocità di moto viene augumentata*.

See also [Discorso intorno alle cose che stanno in su l'acqua](http://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Discorso_intorno_alle_cose_che_stanno_in_su_l%27acqua_o_che_in_quella_si_muovono) (1612) :

> *Momento*, appresso i meccanici, significa quella virtù, quella forza, quella efficacia,
>   con la quale il motor muove e 'l mobile resiste; la qual virtù depende non solo dalla semplice gravità, ma dalla velocità del moto, dalle diverse inclinazioni degli spazii sopra i quali si fa il moto, perché più fa impeto un grave descendente in uno spazio molto declive che in un meno. Ed in somma, qualunque si sia la cagione di tal virtù, ella tuttavia ritien nome di momento. […]
>
> Come, per esemplo, due pesi d'assoluta gravità eguali, posti in bilancia di braccia eguali, restano in equilibrio, né s'inclina l'uno alzando l'altro; perché l'egualità delle distanze di ambedue dal centro, sopra il quale la bilancia vien sostenuta e circa il quale ella si muove, fa che tali pesi, movendosi essa bilancia, passerebbono nello stesso tempo spazii eguali, cioè si moverieno con eguali velocità, onde non è ragione alcuna, per la quale questo peso più di quello, o quello più di questo, si debba abbassare; e per ciò si fa l'equilibrio, e restano i momenti loro di virtù simili ed eguali.

The source for Galileo’s “dynamical” analysis of the balance is the pseudo-Aristotle, [Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics_%28Aristotle%29) [Greek: *Μηχανικά*; see also Morris Cohen & IE Drabkin (editor), [A Source Book in Greek Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674823206) (1948), page 189], where the balance is analyzed in terms of the *power* of the agency that sets a body in motion, defined as the product of the weight of the body and the velocity of the motion that the body acquires.

Comment: In early 21st century (2015), the french word for *momentum* is *quantité de mouvement*. The term *moment* is reserved for *angular momentum.*

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans Previous to 2015, the French word *moment* = "momentum" or "moment", right?

Comment: @Geremia : while the French moment is obviously cognate of the Latin momentum, I don't know if it ever was used with this meaning in French. The answer above contains an example from 1758 using the term "quantité de mouvement" ("amount of motion") which is still the modern denomination. We also sometimes use "impulsion" for  the same quantity. "moment" is used for generalised  (e.g. angular) momentum